# Google Maps Api - Get region polygon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there any way to get the polygon of a region with Google Maps.

If I search Uruguay, Artigas on maps.google.com I see the polygon defined on google maps. I just want to know if there's any way to get that polygon as a polygon string something like :

```
POLYGON((-30.721177988787208 -57.799072265625,-30.74006522890486 -57.6947021484375,-30.83444587394299 -57.557373046875,-30.82501197883239 -57.4639892578125,-30.914596532660827 -57.3486328125,-30.914596532660827 -57.293701171875,-30.94286898846197 -57.23876953125,-31.0182213150299 -57.1673583984375,-31.04646309161982 -57.073974609375,-31.0182213150299 -56.9805908203125,-31.037050096684133 -56.75537109375,-31.013513538113187 -56.6619873046875,-30.919309189078987 -56.44775390625,-30.88160143916058 -56.4312744140625,-30.843878841917167 -56.3983154296875,-30.89574358586453 -56.304931640625,-30.92873380543503 -56.129150390625,-30.985261993549237 -56.1346435546875,-31.065286288898154 -55.997314453125,-30.89574358586453 -56.019287109375,-30.853310882590385 -55.986328125,-30.7542282296686 -56.0577392578125,-30.688116414784933 -56.1566162109375,-30.607776881823785 -56.1895751953125,-30.522638797984513 -56.2994384765625,-30.454444979419478 -56.39127731323242,-30.42965556740803 -56.41556739807129,-30.38620340463919 -56.456851959228516,-30.281009229934632 -56.612548828125,-30.20982806645406 -56.6400146484375,-30.138595376973615 -56.7828369140625,-30.086325365908422 -56.810302734375,-30.07681875693942 -56.9036865234375,-30.110087890214736 -56.93115234375,-30.08157217563409 -57.01904296875,-30.0910783277407 -57.0904541015625,-30.21932186689575 -57.183837890625,-30.252542952311455 -57.161865234375,-30.27626542352284 -57.249755859375,-30.257287905035867 -57.32666015625,-30.295239273123176 -57.403564453125,-30.266777122804427 -57.4749755859375,-30.281009229934632 -57.5189208984375,-30.243052359289663 -57.568359375,-30.176592552395444 -57.601318359375,-30.176592552395444 -57.6617431640625,-30.252542952311455 -57.6177978515625,-30.361618834464707 -57.645263671875,-30.503709081429662 -57.8924560546875,-30.593592390615303 -57.8924560546875,-30.64086594941738 -57.8485107421875,-30.721177988787208 -57.799072265625))
```

I searched a lot and see no reference on Google Maps Api and similar searches on StackOverflow have solutions for US country, but I need from a not so popular country (Uruguay)

Any direction but create the polygon myself (which is what I'm currently doing) will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the Polygons from [The Natural Earth Data set in FusionTables](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTablesLayer_linktoD.html?lat=-30.614578&lng=-56.956969&zoom=9&type=m&tableid=19lLpgsKdJRHL2O4fNmJ406ri9JtpIIk8a-AchA&tablequery=%27kml_4326%27&tablewhere=name_0%20contains%20%27Uruguay%27%20AND%20name_1%20contains%20%27Artigas%27) or as KMZ from http://www.gadm.org/

Comment: Really useful answer and links. However, i dont understand how to accually use this tool. How do you extract the polygon information for a region using these tools?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your platform. For iOS i create a GMSMutablePath with my coordinates then you can call, GMSCoordinateBounds(path: myMutablePath)

This is in the iOS Google Maps SDK. Not sure if there is an equivalent for web.

Comment: sorry i know this is a late answer.

Comment: Does anyone has answer or what can be done?